# Protect source code at delopment time in tfs

Tags: design-time, source-code-protection

I use TFS , My question is how can i sure about that developer who work on a project can not copy source file and evict or extract them from office by Email,flash memory,USB,... ?
Is there any solution with TFS?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you can't trust your developers with the source code, they're never going to get work done.

Answer (score 2):

TFS has no ability to do this, once a file has been retrieved from TFS it is just another text file on your computer you will have to use other tools to do what you want.

Opening it up to tools outside of TFS it is extremely difficult to do what you want to do but it is possible. Your best option is contact a security firm that often works with government defense contractors and have them set up your network IT security, some government defense contractors have the same requirements as you list and they would know all the things you would need to do.

Off the top of my head some of the things you will likely need to do is:

- Use group policy to block writeable media from being used to block flash drives and CD-Rs.
- Block internet access to stop webmail.
- Block printing to stop people printing out the source then using a scanner and OCR software on another computer to turn it back in to code.
- Not allow any device that can take photographs in areas where source code may be on screen as the same OCR procedure could be done with photographs.

This list is no where near complete and I would recommend contacting a security firm to get a complete list.